# How do I remove a device from Firefox Sync?

Tags: firefox, sync, user-accounts, firefox-profile, firefox-sync

I've got some old devices and Firefox profiles that used to sync with my Firefox Sync account, but those devices and browser profiles no longer exist. And yet their browser tabs still appear in Firefox Sync.

How do I remove these devices from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting your Sync password. The downside is you have to re-enter it on every device but this might solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe, the things have changed since your answer but I just have updated my password and all the old devices are still there. Also I'm not asked for the new password on another device (at least just yet).